# Build from linuxserver\deluge

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'd like to be able to use a Dockerfile with the linuxserver\deluge image but I'm unsure what is the correct way to do this in a docker-compose.yaml file.

```
docker create \
--name=deluge \
--net=host \
-e PUID=1001 \
-e PGID=1001 \
-e UMASK_SET=<022> \
-e TZ=<timezone> \
-v </path/to/deluge/config>:/config \
-v </path/to/your/downloads>:/downloads \
--restart unless-stopped \
linuxserver/deluge
```

Can someone help me convert this please so that I can use a Dockerfile

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The following `docker-compose.yml` file is similar to your command :

```
version: "3"

services:
  deluge:
    container_name: deluge
    image: linuxserver/deluge
    environment:
      - PUID=1001
      - PGID=1001
      - UMASK_SET=<022>
      - TZ=<timezone>
    volumes:
      - </path/to/deluge/config>:/config
      - </path/to/your/downloads>:/downloads
    restart: unless-stopped
    network_mode: host
```

[Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) is a great place to find the mapping between `docker` options and `docker-compose` syntax. Here is a recap of what have been used for this example :

- `--name` => `container_name`
- `-e` => `environment` (array of `key=value`)
- `-v` => `volumes` (array of `volume_or_folder_on_host:/path/inside/container`)
- `--restart <policy>` => `restart: <policy>`
- `--net=xxxx` => `network_mode`

You can now run `docker-compose up` to start all your services (only `deluge` here) instead of your `docker run` command.